# Retrieve data array sent through $.get in jquery inside servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

I'm using jQuery to POST data to server and render the resulting responseText in div as follows:

```
var data = { 'lang[]' : []};
$.post("Data", data, function(responseText) {
   $('#otherdiv').html(responseText);
});
```

Suppose the data is populated properly using :

```
data['lang[]'].push($(this).val());
```

At the server side (in a Java servlet) when I'm using:

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("lang");
```

It always says values are `null`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give more complete code from the servlet? The current code only tells us how you read the parameter into Java, not how you are creating the response.

Comment: here's the code
<http://pastebin.com/wWe2Zz6f>
the first function, calling list servlet and displaying is fine
second function call the servlet, but data is not recognized or may be used incorrect parameters to retrieve it.

Comment: i donno why <pastebin.com/wWe2Zz6f> didn't work properly,
when lang[] created with req values,sent to servlet,
in servlet the parameter name is different, we should use lang[][]
then it worked properly. But while creating an array each value is appended with /, donno why, so did some string manipulation in servlet and used it accordingly .

Answer (score -1):

Use `lang` instead of `lang[]`.

HTML Form elements are identified by their id/name whether its single value field or a  list/array.

Comment: passing arrays of data to the server
          $.get("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"]} );
<http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/>
so i have to use lang[] array